# Function string => record member in erlang

Tags: erlang, records

I'm wondering how can i define function, which as an argument takes a string and returns a member of the record.
For example with the record

```
-record(measurement, { temperature, pm2p5, pm10, pressure, humidity, others=[]}).
```

And the fragment of my function:

```
update_measurement(Measurement, Type_as_String, Value) -> 
    Measurement#measurement{get_type(Type_as_String) = Value}
```

I want to update a value by passing a type as string, and I don't have an idea to define the function `get_type(Type_as_String)`.
I've tried with atoms, but it didn't work.

Something like

```
update_measurement(Measurement, Type_as_String, Value) ->
    case Type_as_String of
        "temperature" -> Measurement#measurement{temperature = Value};
        "humidity" -> Measurement#measurement{humidity = Value};
...
```

isn't ok, because i want to reuse this pattern in other functions.

Comment: You mean `binary_to_atom`? But it fact it seems a bit strange to me; can't you just write all the matchers instead?

Comment: No, i defined `get_type(Type_as_String)->
"temperature"->temperature; 
"humidity"->humidity; ....` but didn't work

Comment: Sorry, don't get it: is your String a Binary or List? If latter (`"temperature"`), use `list_to_atom/1` instead. Like `list_to_atom("temperature") => temperature`.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not your biggest concern:

```
update_measurement(Measurement, Type_as_String, Value) ->
    update_field(Measurement, Type_as_String, Value).

update_field(#measurement{} = Record, SKey, Value) ->
     update_field(Record, SKey, Value, record_info(fields, measurement));
% add other records here
update_field(_, _, _) -> error(bad_record).

update_field(Record, SKey, Value, Fields) ->
    update_field(Record, list_to_existing_atom(SKey), Value, Fields, 2).

update_field(Record, Key, Value, [Key|_], N) ->
    setelement(N, Record, Value);
update_field(Record, Key, Value, [_|Fields], N) ->
    update_field(Record, Key, Value, Fields, N+1);
update_field(_, _, _, [], _) ->
    error(bad_key).
```

Note `record_info/2` is not a real function but you have to provide `measurement` as a compile time constant.